# Git push executes unwanter Gitlab runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm new to GitLab CI. Constructed very simple YAML just for test purposes. I configured runner with shell executor on my AWS machine and register it properly. In Settings/Pipelines I see activated runner. When I push something on my repository following YAML should be executed: docker-auto-scale

```
before_script:
  - npm install

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

publish:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - node app.js
```

Instead completly another runner is continouosly started (whatever I change - even when I turn off runner on my machine). It is runner with ID: Runner:  #40786. In logs I can read:

Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.0 (413da38)
  on docker-auto-scale (e11ae361)
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.1 ...

I didn't even have Docker executor - I chose shell one. What is going on? Please support.

Comment: What machine is it running on if you say you don't have any docker runners?

Comment: What do you mean by asking what machine? It's AWS machine. It has runner configure to work with shell.

Comment: It's configured to run a shell runner but it's running a docker runner?

Answer (score 0):

When you registered the new runner, did you give it a tag?

if so, and it would be e.g. `my_tag` modify your yaml file and append:

```
publish:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - node app.js
  tags:
  - my_tag
```

otherwise the build will be picked up by a shared runner.